# Adding ScrollView to my layout messes up my preview

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, scrollview

Here is the code to my activity_main.xml. For some apparent reason, adding a ScrollView complete messes up my Android Preview screen. However when I run the app, everything looks fine like how it should look.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="com.mienapps.justjava.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:text="Toppings"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/whip_cream_checkb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="24dp"
            android:text="Whip Cream"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Quantity"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/decrement"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:onClick="decrement"
                android:text="-"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/increment"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:onClick="increment"
                android:text="+"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Price"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Order Summary"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/price_text_view"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="$0"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/order_summary_text_view"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Subtotal: $0.00\nTax:          7.50%\nTotal:       $0.00"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:onClick="submitOrder"
                android:text="Order"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Here are images of before adding the ScrollView and after adding the ScrollView.

[image: No Scroll View is added]
[image: Screenshot of how it looks when adding a ScrollView]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio rendering when ScrollView is added](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33219121/android-studio-rendering-when-scrollview-is-added)

Comment: Everything messes up preview.  I suggest not even using it, its a POS.

Comment: Nope no duplicate. The preview is fine without the ScrollView, once I add it, the preview just turns out like that.

Answer (score 1):

in ScrollView add attribute `android:fillViewport="true"`

Rotate your Device to feel the app being scroll able

## Also

Search well next time as there is an answer here so this is Duplicated question
[How to make a LinearLayout scrollable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416689/how-to-make-a-linearlayout-scrollable)

Comment: No luck as well =(, running the App, everything looks fine and it shows the App bar, it is only the preview that is messed up, so I am not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You should make `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` of the first `LinearLayout`. Hope it can help you!!

Comment: No luck, running the App, everything looks fine and it shows the App bar, it is only the preview that is messed up, so I am not sure what is going on.